# Output token values within body in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using Orchard CMS and I have a custom form that I want to redirect to a confirmation page after it has been submitted. On this page I would like to output some of the details from the submitted form.

To achieve this I am planning on setting up a workflow which performs a redirect action and passes specific form values through in the query string of the URL that it redirects to.

Is there a way to output these query string values from within the BodyPart of the page that I'm redirecting to? Can I embed tokens within the body of the page?

Is there an alternative method to achieve this using the built-in features of Orchard?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Orchard 1.9 will contain Orchard.Tokens.HtmlFilter within the Orchard.Tokens module.

1.9 is imminent, they are just checking it now. You can download the 1.x source. And I have also noticed a 1.9-int source, which is probably what they are using to prep 1.9 for distribution.

You should, with 1.9 (or 1.x or 1.9-int) be able to enable that feature and then do something like:

```
#{Content.Fields.MyForm.FirstName}
```

within the Body of a page (or content type with the BodyPart), for example.